# Determine if a JavaScript property has a getter or setter defined?

Tags: javascript, properties, getter-setter

Is it possible, given an object and property name to determine if that property is defined using either a getter or setter, or is it completely transparent? I only want to define a getter/setter if there is not already one defined on the property.

I need it to work in WebKit/Firefox.

Comment: How are your getter and setters methods defined? **getSomething** and **setSomething**?

Comment: No, using true JavaScript getters and setters with `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`.

Comment: None of the answers below work if you're using ES6 classes. ```class Box {
 get type() {
 return "Box";
 }
}

var box = new Box();
var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(box, "type");
console.log(desc); // undefined```

Comment: @Snowman so uh... what's the solution in that case?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)?

Comment: OK in that case I don't think its possible, unless Safari also supports `lookupGetter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/LookupGetter

Comment: Interesting note: `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` is useful for determining if an object has a getter/setter defined *locally*, whereas `__lookupGetter__` will actually return a getter defined on the prototype as well.

Comment: This method does not work with class objects. Right ? I created a test case but didn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bas-m4nxo?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 36):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop)`

For example:

```
var obj = { first: 1 }
obj.__defineGetter__('second', function() { return 2; });

// get descriptors
var descriptor1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'first');
var descriptor2 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'second');

// check if it's a getter

descriptor2.get
// returns function () { return 2; }

descriptor1.get
// returns undefined
```

Comment: Jim gets my vote for having the example inline. BOOM.

Comment: Note that it's get**Own**PropertyDescriptor, so it won't include inherited properties or ones defined on prototype.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

```
function isGetter (obj, prop) {
  return !!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop)['get']
}
```

Usage:

```
obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  get bar() { return 'bar' }
}

isGetter(obj, 'bar') // will return true
isGetter(obj, 'foo') // will return false
```

Comment: This answer is an update of Jim Schubert answer because [`__defineGetter__` got deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) since 2011.

Comment: My original intention was to edit Jim's answer to _"add updates as the post ages"_ as it is mention in [Stack Overflow Help > Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). This edit was rejected with the reason: _“This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.”_. Therefore that's the reason for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> `Object.defineProperty's` `get` or `set` Method default value will be undefined if its not defined in the descriptor. This is ideal way to identify.

Let's say example:

```
var User = {};

Object.defineProperty(User, 'name', {
    get: function () {
        return _name;
    },
    enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(User, 'designation', {
    get: function () {
        return _designation;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        _designation = val;
    },
    enumerable: true
});


var d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(User, 'name');
console.log(d.set == undefined);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score -1):

Find the sample Object template for your java Script requirement:

```
var Man=function(n,a){
  var name,age;

  function getName(){
       return this.name;
  }

  function getAge(){
       return this.age;
  }
  function create(){
       this.name=n;
       this.age=a;
       console.log('new object created');
  }

  function setAge(age){
       this.age=age;
  }

  function setName(name){
      this.name=name;
  }
  return{
   name:n,
   age:a,
   getName:getName,
   getAge:getAge,
   setName:setName,
   setAge:setAge
  };
}

var m1=new Man('Chaiguy',30);

// To check if Property exist for an Object
console.log(m1.hasOwnProperty('name'));

// To get the name and age of the object

console.log(m1.getName()+' is '+m1.getAge()+' years old.');
```