# showing 3 pictures randomly from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a drag and drop quiz for kids.

I have `3 letters` and they have to put it in `3 boxes` to make a word. I'm using `jQuery` and somehow i can't modify this code to show the pictures. i think, i need to make a `two dimensional array` but i don't know how to access it and show the pictures and also to add the things in this `for..loop`,

can you please help !!

```
this is the whole code 

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>A jQuery Drag-and-Drop Number Cards Game</title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#cardPile').html( '' );
  $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten' ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 

  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 10 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wideBox">
  <h1>Drag-and-Drop with jQuery: Your Essential Guide</h1>
  <h2>A Number Cards Game</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">

  <div id="cardPile"> </div>
  <div id="cardSlots"> </div>

  <div id="successMessage">
    <h2>You did it!</h2>
    <button onclick="init()">Play Again</button>
  </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

i want to put pictures instead of the numbers i tried doing this

```
 for ( var i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }
```

but it gave me the same picture for the same letter 3 times .. i want 3 pictures of different letters

Comment: Why don't use angularjs with ngdraggable? The learning may be hard since you have challenges with JQuery but that is worth learning. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your html and a picture or explanation of what you'd like to accomplish

Comment: @SathikKhan I don't think learning a whole new library is going to solve his problem.

Comment: I'm with @Glubus, please add your html

Comment: @Dee994, Checkout my example in original question, if you are still not clear - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35556207/1533666

Comment: @Glubus @ Venkatraman something like this http://www.toupty.com/mots-trois-lettres-1-3.html but i just need to show the images of the letters

Comment: @Glubus @ Venkatraman can you help me now ? :/

Comment: So the content of the div you're adding foreach number is the number itself. How are you getting a picture in the first place? You could try to change that line to `<div><img src="prefix"+numbers[i]+".jpg" /></div>`, assuming you have your pictures stored.

Comment: @glubus $('<div>' + "<img src = \"" + numbers [i]  + ".gif\" width = \"105\" height = \"100\" />"+ '</div>') i did this and it worked :D thank you very much :D

Comment: @Glubus haha how funny now everything "looks" like what i want but they are not dropped in the right place .. like all the events were shut down i can only drag them and drop them 
programming is fun -_-

Comment: @Dee994 Well at least we all think so, think of it as a puzzle! Like your game! Only... harder.

Comment: @Glubus yes ! i'll try ,, thank you very much :)