# Can't add new property to subclass

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm attempting to basically write a custom ORM for a small project and I am using a class to set up my records, by default all records will pass through a sort of type checker that will convert any values based on what I said they should be

```
export default class Record {
  constructor(...props) {
    const [model, data] = props;
    forOwn(data, (value, key) => {
      if (model.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = attr(model[key], value);
      } else {
        this[key] = value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This works just fine by looping over an array of data and creating new instances from it

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  serializedData.push(new Item(model, item));
});
```

Where `Item` is just a simple extended class

```
class Item extends Record {
  constructor(...props) { super(...props); }
}
```

Here is where I'm having a problem, I want to add a new `itemImage` property to the `Item` subclass that will take some existing values and create a URL from them.

I've tried both of these that I've found from searching this on the net and neither works

```
Reflect.defineProperty(Item.prototype, 'itemImage', {
  get() {
    return `//res.cloudinary.com/***/image/upload/${this.image.image_crop}/${this.image.image_version}/${this.auction_code}/${this.image.original_image_name}`;
  }
});
```

And

```
class Item extends Record {
  ...

  get itemImage() {
    return this.getItemImage();
  }
  getItemImage() {
    return `//res.cloudinary.com/***/image/upload/${this.image.image_crop}/${this.image.image_version}/${this.auction_code}/${this.image.original_image_name}`;
  }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

***EDIT***

Here is what `attr` does

```
const attr = (type, data) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'number':
      return parseFloat(data);
    case 'string':
      return data.toString();
    case 'object':
      if (typeof data === 'string' && data.indexOf('{') > -1) {
        return JSON.parse(data);
      } else {
        return data;
      }
  }
};
```

Here is a full Sandbox with react to demonstrate

https://codesandbox.io/s/7m388jwk1q

Comment: Not related to your question, but FYI you should use `Object.defineProperty` over `Reflect.defineProperty`, otherwise you risk silently swallowing an error if setting the property fails.

Comment: Whats `attr()` doing?

Comment: Would you be able to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @JonasW. added the `attr()` function reference. @JoeWarner added a jsfiddle link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined

Comment: @JonasW. I see it doesn't have the property but that doesn't solve my problem, it just shows what I already know

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to subclass getters. The issue is in your data format.

Take a look at the `image` property:

```
"image": "[{\"original_image_name\":\"iqsnzsutgbpgqsztani5.png\",\"image_crop\":\"c_crop,h_450,w_1125\"}]"
```

When it is parsed by `attr` function, it becomes an array, **not an object**. So you can't access fields like this: `${this.image.image_crop}`.

But everything works fine if you remove the square brackets. Or, if you can't change the data format, just access the image like this: `${this.image[0].image_crop}`

Comment: So it seems to be kind of working, I can console log and see it there but when I try to render to the page (in my case with react) I see nothing. Not sure why, I tried adding `()` to the end but it complains that it's not a function, which is what I expect

Comment: @Jordan _I tried adding () to the end_ - to the end of what? And how do you render the page? What data is involved in this? It would be nice if you added some details about what you are trying to do next

Comment: I updated the original question with a link to a sandbox instead of jsfiddle where I have put just the relevant code and pieces in and am attempting to render to the page the `itemImage` property