# Is there a backwards compatible way to update a library to use getters?

Tags: javascript

Assuming a library with a function like:

```
class Stuff {
  total () {
    return 4; // might be some calculation
  }
}
```

But you want to update it to use a getter, like:

```
class Stuff {
  get total () {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make a change like this in a backwards compatible way? So code that uses the library assuming a function doesn't break?

```
stuff.total   // should work with new version
stuff.total() // hopefully this still works
```

Edit: This question is more about library evolution (more general). The other one is about a particular solution and from a call-site perspective.

Comment: umm a `getter` is a function....

Comment: True, however my answer provides a wrapper which you can use to detect this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if a JavaScript property has a getter or setter defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do this. `stuff.total` should either be a number or a function, but not both. That will make for very confusing and difficult to maintain code in the future.

That said, you can do something along the lines of what you want:

```js
class Stuff {
  get total () {
    const callable = function ( ) {
      return 4;
    };
    callable[Symbol.toPrimitive] = callable;
    return callable;
  }
}

const stuff = new Stuff;
console.log( stuff.total );
console.log( stuff.total( ) );
console.log( 1 + stuff.total );
console.log( 1 + stuff.total( ) );

// stuff.total is a function, not a number!
console.log( typeof stuff.total );
console.log( stuff.total.toString( ) );

// But if it's implicitly coerced to a string, it's toString is not called:
console.log( '' + stuff.total);
console.log( `${stuff.total}` );
```

There are some caveats though. `stuff.total` is a getter here that is returning a function, not a number. Using that function anywhere a primitive is expected results in the function being called and it's return value being used instead, but it is still really a function. That is evident when you log `stuff.total.toString( )` or `typeof stuff.total`.

Comment: Haha that's messed up. I really need to read up on Symbols :P

Comment: @Olian04 Symbol.toPrimitive is kind of like valueOf and toString combined, however it can also accept a `hint` argument that tells you some information about the context it is being called in. I did not use that here, but it can be useful. If you do `+stuff.total`, the first argument of callable would be `'number'`. If you do `\`${stuff.total}\``, the first argument of callable would be `'string'`.

Comment: Ok, probably not worth it. But i'll flag this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is mostly "no", but partly "it depends".

It comes down to how the existing code is going to use the result. In some cases, you could make a getter work by returning a function, but not in other cases.

Your code example shows a function that returns a simple primitive number, which makes things a little more difficult. In cases where the getter's result is used in such a way that its `.valueOf()` method will be automatically invoked, you can get the desired behavior if you return a function with the `.valueOf()` overridden.

```js
class Doer {
  get total () {
    var f = function() { return f.valueOf() };
    f.valueOf = function() { return 4 };
    return f
  }
}

const d = new Doer();

const x = 10 + d.total();
const y = 10 + d.total; // The addition forces the .valueOf() evaluation

console.log(x, y);
```

However `d.total` is still ultimately a function and not the number `4`.

If you were returning an object, you could perhaps fake it a bit more easily by returning an object that inherits from `Function.prototype`, but still it will greatly depend on the actual usage.