# hasOwnProperty does not work for MessageEvent object

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why `hasOwnProperty` does not work for some special JavaScript Objects like `MessageEvent` (I don't know if there are others, If you know please let me know).

```
const message = new MessageEvent('worker', { data: 'hello' });

message.hasOwnProperty('data');  // false

console.log(message.data);  // 'hello'

'data' in message // true
```

How can I be sure  `data` is inside `message`?  If I use `in` is tricky because data can exists in the inherited objects and `in` returns `true` for that case as well.

Comment: how about, (typeof message.data != 'undefined') ?

Comment: I really want to know if data exists as a property there... because you can do {data: undefined} so your check will fail... even if data is there defined as undefined.

Comment: A `MessageEvent` object always has a `data` property. If you don't specify it explicitly, it defaults to `null`. So what's the point of checking for it?

Comment: the point is that I have created a function which checks if a nested property exists in an object.  And when I want to check message.data.a.b   my function fails because data is not recognized... https://github.com/vsambor/get-value-safely/blob/master/index.js

Comment: `message.__proto__` shows `MessageEventPrototype { ..., data: Getter, … }`, so that's what you probably observe

Comment: The `data` property appears to be on the *prototype* for some reason. Iterating over the `in` properties, the only one that passes `hasOwnProperty` is `isTrusted` (same thing that `Object.keys` returns). But `console.log`ging the `message` *looks* to have `data` (and many other properties) directly on the object, not on the prototype...? https://jsfiddle.net/mpzxLu9c/ Is the console lying to me, or what?

Comment: It's not an ordinary object property, it's implemented using a getter method in the prototype.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `data` is inherited from `Event`. I guess, thats the reason its in proto.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined/8591909 for how to detect a getter method.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried what you proposed `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(message, 'data'));` this gives `undefined` instead of a descriptor.

Comment: @V.Sambor He said it's inherited from the prototype, it's not an own property of the instance. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeof(message), 'data')`

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, this way I can get the data descriptor. Do you know if there is a way to determine if an object is a `simple` object or some special object like MessageEvent?

Comment: @V.Sambor `Object.getPrototypeOf(…) == Object.prototype` would do, I guess (if that is what you mean by "simple", there may be other definitions)