# How to tell if an ES6 class has a getter of given name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It seems like ES6 classes don't respond to .hasOwnProperty as one might expect.

If you have this class:

```
class Foo {
  get index() {
    return 12;
  }
}
```

This code will return false:

```
let myFoo = new Foo();
alert(myFoo.hasOwnProperty("index"); <-- alerts "false"
```

I could test if a property  returns "undefined" but that wouldn't discriminate between a "get" that returns undefined and an class object that has no method with the given name, i.e.

```
class Foo {
  get index() {
    return 12;
  }
  get position() {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Whats the right way to test for presence of a "getter" or "setter" on ES6 classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if a JavaScript property has a getter or setter defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined)

Comment: See also [`get` Vs. `defineProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#get_Vs._defineProperty)

Comment: don't use classes in Javascript and you will not have this problem :)

Comment: OK, thanks that first one doesn't seem to quite do it, but the MDN page suggests this:   Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(myFoo), 'index');  which is kind of a mounthful but at least works.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I wouldn't have this problem if I just use ruby also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes are a bit weird in JavaScript, as it is basically just prototype inheritance. So in this case, `index` should exist on the prototype of `myFoo`:

```js
class Foo {
  get index() {
    return 12;
  }
}
const myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.hasOwnProperty('index'); // false
Object.getPrototypeOf(myFoo).hasOwnProperty('index'); // true
```

Comment: Test for if setter exists?

Comment: There are functions dedicated for looking up getters/setters with e.g. `myFoo.__lookupSetter__('index')`, but they have been deprecated. 

I believe that your best bet is to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to distinguish between getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks.  Worth noting for future readers that what you described above works for class instances, won't work for plan javascript objects.  So if you want a function like

Answer (score 2):

as @zero298 link;

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 'index').get
```

Comment: so uh... this doesn't work if the setter is declared in the non-class way, is that expected?  Do I need to test both ways if I don't know if the object in question is from a class or not?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` might return `undefined` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). If this might apply to your case (most likely) don't forget the question mark: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 'index')?.get
`