# Is there a built-in JavaScript function for checking if a property OR property getter exists within a class instance?

Tags: javascript

I have a use case of:

[image: Use case]

Wherein it's a deeply polymorphic class utilizing mixins which preserve the inheritance chain, functionally similar to the code below.  I already have a `createSettings()` method which exists at each layer to create a settings object from another settings object, which I would like to be able to call from a context similar the `_innerStore` method to generate the region in blue via `this.createSettings(this)` (the `createSettings` argument within the `createSettings()` method gets initialized to an empty Object at the base level of mixins, each via the `super.createSettings()` line.)

The issue arises in the `hasOwnProperty` call in the red section, which can not identify the existence of a `type` property, which exists as a property getter (`_type` on the other hand would work, but that would break the reusability `createSettings` for use with both a general `settings` object.)

What I'd like would be a (fast, ideally in-built) method for doing something akin to the "recursive trash method" in the code below, which will work on property getters, but also on `Object` properties.

```
class A {
    constructor() {
    this._foo = 'Foo';
  }
  get foo() { return (this._foo); }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

let b = new B();

// recursive trash method
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b.__proto__, 'foo'));
// return undefined
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b.__proto__.__proto__, 'foo'));
// returns property definition which could be used
```

My ideal here would be to call either of the following final two calls with the same result in `c` and `d`:

```
class A {
    constructor(settings) {
    this._foo = (settings.hasOwnProperty('foo') ? settings.foo : 'foo');
  }
  get foo() { return (this._foo); }
  
  static createSettings(settings, createSettings) { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  static createSettings(settings, createSettings) { ... }
}

let b = new B();

let c = new B(B.createSettings({
    foo: 'foo'
}));

let d = new B(B.createSettings(b));
```

An example of a `hasProperty()` function working as I'd like would be:

```
class A {
    constructor(settings) {
    this._foo = (settings.hasOwnProperty('foo') ? settings.foo : 'foo');
  }
  get foo() { return (this._foo); }
  static hasProperty(obj, propertyName) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) { return (true); }
    let o = obj;
    while (o = o.__proto__) {
        let p = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'foo');
      if (p !== undefined) {
        if (p.hasOwnProperty('get')) { return (true); }
      }
    }
    return (false);
  }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(settings) {
    super(settings);
  }
}

let b = new B({ });

console.log(b.constructor.hasProperty(b, 'foo'));
// returns true
console.log(b.constructor.hasProperty({'foo': 'bar'}, 'foo'));
// returns true
```

However I'd prefer something that doesn't have to recurse over the prototype chain for this if at all possible (or at least, if that's how it works under the hood, something which does so in the JS engine itself instead of in userland.)

Comment: Seems like a wordy duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined/8591909

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if a JavaScript property has a getter or setter defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined)