# Builtin to check if javascript setter defined in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591873/determine-if-a-javascript-property-has-a-getter-or-setter-defined) explains how to tell if an object has a setter defined on that very object but it may still have one elsewhere in the prototype chain.  Is there a builtin that lets one check if there is a setter defined somewhere on the prototype chain or does one simply have to recurse and test each element on the prototype chain?

Comment: `typeof foo.bar !== 'undefined'`…?

Comment: That doesn't tell me if a setter has been defined.  I might have a getter but no setter.  Or the value returned by the getter might be undefined.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: `foo.__lookupGetter_('bar') // function bar()`, but it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such builtin. You'll have to traverse the prototype chain and call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` on every object.